# Renaming of a loaded browser plugin dll fails in XP (ie 8)

Tags: internet-explorer, dll, bho, windows-xp-sp3

I have searched the site already and didn't find any mexact matching question. Sorry if I am repeating it.

We have a browser plugin which needs to update itself. That means, the dll itself will rename the currently loaded dll (in the same directory) and put the newer file instead. While this is working fine in Vista and onwards, we are facing issue in XP. We use MoveFileEx to perform the operation and in XP we are getting the sharing violation error message.

OS : Win XP SP 3
Browser : IE 8
Error : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
API Used : MoveFileEx with MOVEFILE_REPLACE_EXISTING option
Language : C++

We noticed the same error in Windows Explorer. There is no issue with access privilege, we already checked it. And the most confusing thing is that, we didn't face any issue when we did the same in Firefox with the exact same dll.

Can somebody help? Let me know if anymore details are required.